# Are fully faithful functors stable under pullback?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be locally small categories, let $I:A\to C$ be a fully faithful functor and let $F:B\to C$ be any functor. Is the pullback $F^*I: A \times_C B\to B$ still fully faithful?

If yes, is there an underlying orthogonal factorization system?

Any reference would also be welcome.

Comment: Of course one can also just check it directly with the definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [bijective-on-objects/fully faithful](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28bo%2C+ff%29+factorization+system) orthogonal factorisation system on Cat. Hence, as a right class of a factorisation system, fully faithful functors are [closed under pullback](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system#closure_properties) in Cat.

For another reference, see also Riehl's [notes on Factorisation Systems](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/factorization.pdf).

Comment: +1 - really slick answer